Spring JPA: How to fetch a Many to Many Relation, with the Join table as separate entity, without infinite recursion
I have two entities, user and role with a many-to-many mapping, I maintain a join table entity called users_roles to maintain some other rel fields,
// ignored trivial fields
@Entity
public class User {
    private name;
    
    @OneToMany
    private List<UsersRoles> usersRoles;
}

@Entity
public class Role {
    private name;
    
    @OneToMany
    private List<UsersRoles> usersRoles;
}

@Entity
public class UsersRoles {
    @ManyToOne
    private List<User> users;

    @ManyToOne
    private List<Role> roles;
    
    // other fields like tenantId

}

What's the proper way to fetch a user by name, if I do
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    Optional<User> getReferenceByName(String name);
}

I get the user object with the usersRoles object, but the usersRoles object contains the users, which in turn contains usersRoles and loops around infinitely.
Ultimately, I have to fetch a user with his role names, I don't actually need the usersRoles object, it's solely introduced to maintain tenantId field for multitenancy. I've a similar dependency with roles and privileges, not sure how to resolve it.
Most of the solutions introduce a DTO to solve the problem, I would need a DTO like the following, but not sure how to map a query to this DTO. I'm fairly new to JPA, so if it's a redundant question kindly point me to the solution.
public class UserDTO {
    private name;
    private List<Role> roles;
}


In this you can use the annotation @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference,
What it does : Annotation used to indicate that associated property is part of two-way linkage between fields; and that its role is "child" (or "back") link.
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany
private List<UsersRoles> usersRoles;

@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToOne
private List<User> users;

These annotations would solve recursion problem.
If you want to map to a DTO class and retrieve, you would need to write hibernate query and this JPA cant do that.
Here is an example:
First create a constructor for the DTO like this :
constructor(String name, List<UserRole> userRoles){
this.name = name;
this.userRoles = userRoles}

and according to this you will need to map the data through hibernate query like this :
@Query(value = "SELECT new UserDTO(user.name, user.roles)
from User user

NOTE : Be mindful about the relation joins.
